# LilyPond: phrasing brackets above the staff

Tags: lilypond

Consider the following piece of sheet music:

[image]

It has right-angle brackets in the beginning and in the end. How can I engrave it with LilyPond?

Here is a template for the piece:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "italiano"

\score {
    \header {
        opus = "Op. 599 №27"
    }
    \new PianoStaff 
    <<
        \new Staff = "right"
        \relative do' {
            \key do \major
            \time 4/4
            \tempo "Allegretto"
            \override Fingering.avoid-slur = #'inside
            \override Fingering.staff-padding = #'()
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(up)
            <do'-4>16 (_[<sol-1> la si] <do-4> _[<sol-1> la si] <do-4> _[sol la <si-3>] <do-1> re mi fa |
            <sol-5> <do,-1> <re-2> <mi-3> <fa-1> sol la <si-4> do8-.) <mi,-1 sol-2>-. <mi-1 sol-3>-. <mi-1 sol-3>-. |
            <fa-2>-.-> <fa-1 re'-5>-. <fa re'>-. <fa re'>-. <mi-2>->-. <mi-1 do'-5>-. <mi do'>-. <mi do'>-. |
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
            <re-2>-.-> <re-1 sol-2 si-4>-. <re sol si>-. <re sol si>-. <mi-1 sol-2 do-5>2 |
            \bar "|."
        }
        \new Dynamics {
            s1 \p |
            s16 \< s4 s8 s16 \! s2 |
        }
        \new Staff = "left"
        \relative do' {
            \key do \major
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
            <do-4 mi-2>4-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. |
            <do mi>-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. |
            <si-5 sol'-1>-. <si sol'>-. <do-4 sol'-1>-. <do sol'>-. |
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
            <sol-5 re'-2 fa-1>-. <sol re' fa>-.
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
            <do-3 mi-1>-. <do mi>-. |
        }
    >>
}
```

## Update

Following @guidot's suggestion, here are the details on the meaning of these brackets (an excerpt from the book, translated from Portuguese).

> In this review of ours we indicate the easiest process to reach perfection and get the most out of these etudes, by working out the difficulties in the form of an exercise or in uninterrupted repetitions, until you get the desired effect. For this purpose, we indicate with the sign ┌ ┐ all the passages to be repeated, breaking them up when certain details need to be studied in advance. By meticulously following this work process, the best and greatest result will be obtained. The passages and their fragments, as we said above, must be studied without interruption, linking the last note of each passage to the first; If possible, the necessary interruption will be made to restart the execution of the passage. Regardless of this form of work, we often indicate variations of rhythms, transports, preparatory exercises and everything else that may contribute to the student's performance. However, we warn you that the sign ┌ ┐ is applied exclusively to determine the repetitions of the excerpts to be perfected, without considering divisions of phrases according to the musical meaning.

Comment: The piece is from Czerny "Practical exercises for beginners" - see [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Practical_Exercises_for_Beginners,_Op.599_(Czerny,_Carl))-, and I'm neither convinced, that the angles are related to phrasing nor that it is a good idea to replicate them without a convincing interpretation of  their meaning.

Comment: @guidot I simply didn't want to retype a couple of paragraphs of explanations from the book about what they are because it is irrelevant to the question. I took the piece from the Joaquim Barrozo's book. It has an explanation in Portuguese at the beginning of the book, in the gist saying that these denote the phrases you have to concentrate on while studying. The book also mentions these are not phrases in the musical sense. Can I reproduce it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the brackets always appear over the top staff for the whole system we can do this

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "italiano"

openBracket = \tweak self-alignment-X #'() \tweak break-visibility #end-of-line-invisible \mark \markup { \path #0.2 #'((moveto 0 0) (lineto 0 2) (lineto 1.3 2)) }
closeBracket = \tweak self-alignment-X #'() \tweak break-visibility #begin-of-line-invisible \mark \markup { \path #0.2 #'((moveto 0 0) (lineto 0 2) (lineto -1.5 2)) }

\score {
    \header {
        opus = "Op. 599 №27"
    }
    \new PianoStaff 
    <<
        \new Staff = "right"
        \relative do' {
            \key do \major
            \time 4/4
            \tempo "Allegretto"
            \override Fingering.avoid-slur = #'inside
            \override Fingering.staff-padding = #'()
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(up)
            <do'-4>16 (_[<sol-1> la si] <do-4> _[<sol-1> la si] <do-4> _[sol la <si-3>] <do-1> re mi fa |
            <sol-5> <do,-1> <re-2> <mi-3> <fa-1> sol la <si-4> do8-.) <mi,-1 sol-2>-. <mi-1 sol-3>-. <mi-1 sol-3>-. |
            \openBracket
            <fa-2>-.-> <fa-1 re'-5>-. <fa re'>-. <fa re'>-. <mi-2>->-. <mi-1 do'-5>-. <mi do'>-. <mi do'>-. |
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
            <re-2>-.-> <re-1 sol-2 si-4>-. <re sol si>-. <re sol si>-. <mi-1 sol-2 do-5>2 |
            \closeBracket
        }
        \new Dynamics {
            s1 \p |
            s16 \< s4 s8 s16 \! s2 |
        }
        \new Staff = "left"
        \relative do' {
            \key do \major
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
            <do-4 mi-2>4-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. |
            <do mi>-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. <do mi>-. |
            <si-5 sol'-1>-. <si sol'>-. <do-4 sol'-1>-. <do sol'>-. |
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
            <sol-5 re'-2 fa-1>-. <sol re' fa>-.
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
            <do-3 mi-1>-. <do mi>-. |
        }
    >>
}
```

In case it isn’t we can either add the Mark_engraver to all Staves so we can have individual marks, or we use a regular TextScript for this and hope the alignment somewhat works.

Comment: Thank you! I have a small problem with this solution. If I add a `\break` _after_ `\closeBracket` and add one more bar, the closing bracket goes to the next line.

Comment: @facetus Sorry, did not think about that. You need to use break-visibility for that. I’ve changed the code so that the opening bracket will appear at the begin of the line and the closing bracket at the end of a line at breaks.

Also note that if you want multiple brackets next to each other you’d want to use the Multimark engraver.

Comment: I tried multimark engraver from here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2011-08/msg00157.html. The brackets are engraved not next to each other, but one above each other.

Comment: I posted another question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/122778/lilypond-stack-order-of-multimark-engraver