# LilyPond: stack order of Multimark engraver

Tags: lilypond, engraving, ottava

I continue my struggle (began [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/120481/lilypond-phrasing-brackets-above-the-staff)) with engraving Barrozo's collection of Czerny exercises. The problem is in engraving brackets that Barrozo uses to mark parts for repetition. Following advice of [Lazy](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/82808/lazy), I used a [multimark engraver](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2011-08/msg00157.html). I don't understand this code and thus don't know how to change the stack order of the marks. Here is my result:
[image]

I want the two brackets between the 6-th and the 7-th bars to be below the octave bracket. How can I do it? I tried changing `outside-staff-priority`, but it didn't help. Maybe `script-priority` can help? But where should I put it?

Here is the full code (sorry, a lot of text)

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "italiano"

openBracket =
    \tweak self-alignment-X #'()
    \tweak break-visibility #end-of-line-invisible
    \mark \markup {
        \path #0.2 #'((moveto 0 0) (lineto 0 2) (lineto 1.3 2))
    }
closeBracket =
    \tweak self-alignment-X #'()
    \tweak break-visibility #begin-of-line-invisible
    \mark \markup {
        \path #0.2 #'((moveto 0 0) (lineto 0 2) (lineto -1.3 2))
    }
doubleBracket =
    \tweak self-alignment-X #'()
    \mark \markup {
        \path #0.2 #'((moveto -0.2 0) (lineto -0.2 2) (lineto -1.5 2)
                      (moveto  0.2 0) (lineto  0.2 2) (lineto  1.5 2))
    }

#(set-global-staff-size 18)

\layout {
    \context {
        \Score
        \omit BarNumber
    }
}

leggermente = #(make-dynamic-script
               (markup #:normal-text #:italic "leggermente"))

#(define (multi-mark-engraver ctx)
    (let
        ((texts '())
         (final-texts '())
         (events '()))

      `(
            (start-translation-timestep
                . ,(lambda (trans)
                (set! final-texts '())))

            (listeners
                (mark-event
                    . ,(lambda (trans ev)
                    (set! events (cons ev events)))))

            (acknowledgers
                (break-alignment-interface
                    . ,(lambda (trans grob source)
                        (for-each
                            (lambda (mark)
                                (set! (ly:grob-parent mark X) grob))
                            texts))))

            (process-music
                . ,(lambda (trans)
                    (for-each
                        (lambda (ev)
                            (let*
                                (
                                    (mark-grob (ly:engraver-make-grob trans 'RehearsalMark ev))
                                    (label (ly:event-property ev 'label))
                                    (formatter (ly:context-property ctx 'markFormatter))
                                )

                                (if
                                    (and (procedure? formatter) (not (markup? label)))
                                    (begin
                                        (if (not (number? label))
                                            (set! label
                                                (ly:context-property ctx 'rehearsalMark)))

                                        (if (and (integer? label)
                                            (exact? label))
                                            (set!
                                                (ly:context-property ctx 'rehearsalMark)
                                                (1+ label)))

                                        (if (number? label)
                                            (set! label (apply formatter (list label ctx)))
                                            (ly:warning "rehearsalMark must have integer value"))))

                                (if (markup? label)
                                    (begin
                                        (set! (ly:grob-property mark-grob 'text) label)
                                        (let ((dir (ly:event-property ev 'direction)))
                                            (and (ly:dir? dir)
                                                (set! (ly:grob-property mark-grob 'direction) dir))))
                                    (ly:warning "mark label must be a markup object"))

                                (set! texts (cons mark-grob texts))))
                        (reverse events))))

            (stop-translation-timestep
                . ,(lambda (trans)
                    (if (pair? texts)
                        (let
                            ((staves (ly:context-property ctx 'stavesFound)) (priority-index 0))
                            (for-each
                                (lambda (grob)
                                    (let
                                        ((my-priority (ly:grob-property grob 'outside-staff-priority 1500)))
                                        (for-each (lambda (stave) (ly:pointer-group-interface::add-grob grob 'side-support-elements stave)) staves)
                                        (set! (ly:grob-property grob 'outside-staff-priority) (+ my-priority priority-index))
                                        (set! priority-index (1+ priority-index))
                                        (set! final-texts (cons grob final-texts))))
                                (reverse texts))
                            (set! texts '())
                            (set! events '())))))

            (finalize
                . ,(lambda (trans)
                    (and
                        (pair? final-texts)
                        (for-each
                            (lambda (grob)
                                (set! (ly:grob-property grob 'break-visibility) end-of-line-visible))
                            final-texts)))))))

\score {
    \header {
        opus = "Op. 261 №7"
    }
    \new PianoStaff \with {
        instrumentName = "11."
        \override InstrumentName.font-size = #6
        \override InstrumentName.self-alignment-X = #RIGHT
    } <<
        \new Staff = "правая" \with {}
        \relative do' {
            \key do \major
            \time 2/4
            \tempo "Allegretto vivace"
            \set Timing.baseMoment = #(ly:make-moment 1/32)
            \set Timing.beatStructure = 4, 4, 4, 4
            \openBracket
            do'32-3 (_[sol-1 re'-4 sol,-1]) mi'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 mi32-3 (_[do-1 fa-4 do-1]) sol'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 |
            do,32-3 (_[sol-1 re'-4 sol,-1]) mi'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 mi32-3 (_[do-1 fa-4 do-1]) sol'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 |
            fa32-4 (_[sol-5 mi-3 sol-5]) re16-!-2 \noBeam r16 mi32-3 (_[sol-5 re-2 sol-5]) do,16-!-1 \noBeam r16 |
            \once \override Fingering.avoid-slur = #'inside
            re32-2 (sol-5 re-2 sol-5 si,-1 re-4 si-2 re-4) sol,16-!-1 [sol-!-3 sol-!-2 sol-!-1] \closeBracket |
            \openBracket
            do32-3 (_[sol-1 re'-4 sol,-1]) mi'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 mi32-3 (_[do fa-4 do]) sol'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 |
            \ottava #1 do32-3 (_[sol re'-4 sol,]) mi'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 mi32-3 (_[do fa-4 do]) sol'16-!-5 \noBeam r16 |
            \doubleBracket
            la32-5 (la,-1 la'-5 sol fa-3 mi re-1 do-4 \ottava #0 si-3 la sol-1 fa-4 mi-3 re do-1 si-2 |
            do-1 re mi-3 fa-1 sol-2 la si do-5 do,16-.-1) r r8 \closeBracket
            \bar "|."
        }
        \new Dynamics {
            s16 \p
            \once \override DynamicText.X-offset = 0
            s32 \leggermente s32 s8 s4 | s2 | s2 |
            s32 \> s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s16 s16 s16 s16 \! |
            s32 \p s32 s32 s32 s16 s16 s32 s32 s32 s32 s16 s16 |
            s32 \mf s32 s32 s32 s16 s16 s32 s32 s32 s32 s16 s16 |
            s32 \f s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 s32 |
        }
        \new Staff = "левая" \with {}
        \relative do {
            \clef bass
            \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
            <do-4>16-. _[r <mi-2 sol-1>-.] r do-. _[r <mi sol>-.] r |
            <do-4>-. _[r <mi-2 sol-1>-.] r do-. _[r <mi sol>-.] r |
            <do-5>-. _[r <re-3 sol-1>-.] r <do-4>-. _[r <mi-2 sol-1>-.] r |
            <sol-3 si-1>8-> r8 r4 |
            <do,-4>16-. _[r <mi-2 sol-1>-.] r do-. _[r <mi sol>-.] r |
            <do-4>-. _[r <mi-2 sol-1>-.] r do-. _[r <mi sol>-.] r |
            <fa-5 la-3 re-1>8 r <sol-5 re'-2 fa-1> r |
            <do-3 mi-1>16-. r <do mi>-. r <do mi>-. r r8
        }
    >>
    \layout {
        \context {
            \Score
            \override SpacingSpanner.spacing-increment = 1.1
            \remove "Mark_engraver"
            \consists #multi-mark-engraver
            \consists "Tweak_engraver"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
\tweak outside-staff-priority #100 \doubleBracket
```

At least on my end this works. Note that the priority needs to be lower than the Priority of the OttavaBracket, which defaults to 400.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to know when I should use `\override` or `\tweak`?

Comment: @facetus `\override` sets the default values of a grob for a context. Thus it affects any grob starting at the timeframe this was set. `\tweak` on the other hand sets a property of the music event and thus only affects this single music events. This means that you should use `\override` if you want to affect all occurrences, while `\tweak` can be used to change a single entity. In some cases you could use `\once\override` for this, but this will still affect all grobs in the same timeframe.

Comment: @facetus For example this `\new Voice << c' {\once\override NoteHead.font-size = -2 e'} g' >>` does not work (as the override affects all heads), but this `\new Voice << c' \tweak font-size -2 e' g' >>` does. Of course in your case you can also do `\once\override Score.RehearsalMark.outside-staff-priority = #100 \doubleBracket`. as you do not have multiple Marks at the same time. But it is longer and somewhat depnding on `\doubleBracket` using Marks when it could also use markups or whatever.

Comment: There is a line in the multimark engraver that sets `outside-staff-priority`. Why changing it in the multimark engraver code doesn't change the stack order?

Comment: @facetus The line in question is `(set! (ly:grob-property grob 'outside-staff-priority) (+ my-priority priority-index))`. Changing this *will* change the stackorder, but you should not do this! This part simply adds a little bit to the outside staff priority so that the different marks have different priorities.